# I still see grass seeds in my yard even I rake them

Tags: grass, seeds

I used spreader to put some grass seeds in my back yard. I rake them thoroughly after that. After three days, I was checking my yard and still see bunch of blue grass seed on the ground. Do I need to rake them again.

Comment: This is not a problem. Your raking will have covered *some* of the seeds. In fact if you can still see seeds on the surface, that is a good thing, because birds or other critters haven't eaten everything! Don't forget that "grass" is just a natural plant - nothing rakes *wild* grass seeds into the ground, but the grass still grows.

Comment: @alephzero That was a rather nice way to explain to this OP.  I think you should use that as an answer because that was exactly what they needed to know!

Answer (score 2):

When you seed with new seed the most important thing is not to walk on it or rake! Fruffed up soil, seed, roll and that should be good enough.  Never allow the germinating seed to dry out or be raked.  In about 2 weeks you should be good for the first mowing.

After this first mow you should start training your baby grass to grow deeper to get the moisture.  Water deeply, allow to dry enough where when you walk on your grass the grass blades stay down.  That is the signal to water deeply again.  Do not water again until the grass shows this basic stress signal.  Keep your lawn no shorter than 3 inches!!!  Not 2 1/2 but 3".

Comment: Fruffed up? What it means?

Comment: I know, I make up my own words and forget they aren't real!  The surface compaction 'undone'...gosh.  This is tough.  Hoed and loosened and raked, graded.  Then the seed has a nice 'fluffed' up bed to cuddle up into?  I turn the soft rake over on its backside to mix the soil and seed a little bit then roll with a water filled roller for soil seed contact.  Is there a better word or way to explain breaking up the surface of the soil, loosening up the surface of the soil maybe?  There must be.  Where's my cup of coffee?